# Show that $\widetilde{f}$ is a nondegenerate map?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, bilinear-form, symplectic-geometry, quotient-spaces

Noted by $V, W$ two vectors spaces over the same field $K$ of finite dimensions. Let $f:V\times V\rightarrow W$ a degenerate map. I would show that
$$\widetilde{f}:\widetilde{V}\times \widetilde{V}\rightarrow W$$
is a nondegenerate map, where $\widetilde{V}:= V/\ker{f}$, with $\ker{f}=\{x\in V: \, f(x,y)=0\quad  \forall y\in V\}$ is the subspace kernel of $f$.

**Recall that:**
. A degenerate bilinear form $f:V\times V\rightarrow W$  on a finite-dimensional  vector space $V$ is a bilinear form such that it has a non-trivial kernel. And it is nondegenerate iff it's subspace kernel is trivial.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think you did not make it clearly. Is $f$ symmetric bilinear? And you should also define $\widetilde{f}$ clearly and prove that it's well-defined first of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question to see what happens in passing to the
quotient, but we must to  avoids some simple error. as the
deference between bilinear map and bilinear form. and for a
bilinear map there  are two type of kernel that is left and right,
and this two type are equal in the case of symmetric bilinear map.

so in your context   we speak on the left kernel of $f$ as you
have wrote: $kerf=\{x\in V \mid f(x,y)=0\forall y\in V\}$ and this
is a well subspace of $V$ so $\widetilde{V}=V/kerf$ is a quotient
space, but what is $\widetilde{f}$? that is the problem of lifting
$f$ via the space  $\widetilde{V}=V/kerf
\times\widetilde{V}=V/kerf$, this  is the problem :  when
$\widetilde{f} (\widetilde{x},\widetilde{y})=f(x,y)$ has a sense
for all $x,y\in V$? if you don't suppose $f$ symmetric there no
warrant $\widetilde{f}$ to be well defined.

so we answered the question in the case all good, that is $f$
symmetric and so $\widetilde{f}$ is well defined in this case.

in this case we tack $\{e_1,...,e_m\}$ a basis of $kerf$ and we
complete this basis with $\{e_{m+1},...,e_{m+n}\}$  for obtaining
a basis $\{e_1,...,e_m, e_{m+1},...,e_{m+n}\}$ of $V$ then
$\{\widetilde{e}_{m+1},...,\widetilde{e}_{m+n}\}$ is a basis of
the quotient space $V/kerf$.

we prove that $\widetilde{f}$ is not
degenerate bilinear map. let $x\in V$ such that
$\widetilde{f}(\widetilde{x},
\widetilde{e}_j)=f(x,e_j)=0,\;\forall j\in\{m+1,...,m+n\}$, this
applique that $f(x,e_i)=0,\;\forall i\in\{1,...,m+n\}$ (because
for $i\in\{1,...,m\}$  we have $e_i\in kerf$), so $x\in kerf$ and
$\widetilde{x}=0$ this prove that $\widetilde{f}$ not degenerate.

Comment: note: you can suppose only leftkerf=rightkerf the all are correct; thanks

Comment: Thank you very much m.idaya. Just, I would like to know, where intervenes the hypothesis "symmetric" in your proof?

Comment: to you too: intervene in $\widetilde{f}$  to be well defined; because if
$\widetilde{x}=\widetilde{u}$ and $\widetilde{y}=\widetilde{w}$ we
must have
$\widetilde{f}(\widetilde{x},\widetilde{y})=\widetilde{f}(\widetilde{u},\widetilde{w})$.
but this is true  for all $x,u,y,w\in V$ iff leftkerf=rightkerf.
so when $f$ is symmetric this hold i.e leftkerf=rightkerf.

Comment: sorry I can't correct the latex error in my comment: to read
$\widetilde{f}(\widetilde{x},\widetilde{y})=\widetilde{f}(\widetilde{u},\widetilde{w})$.  all is get in my latex compilation but here are problem

Comment: Ok. Just, what you means by "leftkerf" and "rightkerf"?

Comment: l$eftkerf=\{x\in V\mid f(x,y)=0\forall y\in V\}$ and $rightkerf=\{y\in V\mid f(x,y)=0\forall x\in V\}$

Comment: Ok. Finally, If $f$ is a skew-symmetric map, is that the result is true?

Comment: As $rightkerf=\{y\in V\mid f(x,y)=0\forall x\in V\}=\{y\in V\mid  f(x,y)=-f(y,x)=0=f(y,x) \forall x\in V\}$ in the case when $f$ is a skew-symmetric map. Then, is that the result is correct?

Comment: I apologize for the delay, I was in the companion out of internet
network. the result is also  true  in the case $f$ a skew-symmetric map because $leftkernel(f) =
rigfhtkernel(f)$

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much m. idaya